# The type or namespace 'OData' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I am building a .Net Core OData interface.

I am trying to use the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData' but it throws the error saying 'The type or namespace 'OData' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore'.'

Also, I have downloaded the package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore'.

The question is:
1. Can I use Microsoft.AspNet.OData instead of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData'. Would that affect my OData implementation in .net core?

Thank you.

Comment: This should help : https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/939

Comment: which version of Core are yo using and what version VS?

Comment: Thank you @JaliyaUdagedara :-)

Comment: Core Version - 7.0.0 beta, VS Version - VS 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd C:/temp
dotnet new web  
dotnet add .\temp.csproj package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData --version 7.0.0-*
```

That lets us use the following `using` statement.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
```

instead of

```
using System.Web.OData;
```